# WP7 event handler for selection change for LoopingSelector

Tags: windows-phone-7, loopingselector

So I'm making a currency converter using a LoopingSelector, of course for Windows Phone 7. I made the data source and it's working all fine. I can take the selected items and do things with them. What I need now though, is a way to perform a particular action within my MainPage. I have the following in my data source class:

`public event EventHandler<SelectionChangedEventArgs> SelectionChanged;`

I want to be able to take this event and make some sort of a method in my MainPage which gets invoked every time the selection is changed.

Perhaps it's a silly question. I've looked under tree and rock for the answer before I came here though.
Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well despite the fact that no one answered this I still found the solution.

I first did the following:

`selector1.DataSource.SelectionChanged += new EventHandler<SelectionChangedEventArgs>(selector1_SelectionChanged);`

and then implemented the method:

`private void selector1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            //code
        }`